# How to create typed variables in beforeAll tests?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, mocha.js, jestjs

There is a common scenario I run into. I need to create a variable in the `beforeAll` or each.

```
describe('some test', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const foo = createFoo({}, {});    
  });

  it('returns something', () => {
    // how to access foo?
  });
});
```

If I do it like that I can't access `foo` on `it` tests because it only exists inside `beforeAll` scope.

To be able to access where I need I have to declare `foo` inside `describe`:

```
describe('', () => {
  let foo;
```

Or use

```
this.foo =
```

The problem with both these approaches is that I lose the type information. And I don't have explicit interfaces for the return type of those kind of functions.

Is there a way to declare `foo` somewhere where I can access it later and not lose type information?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`) to relax the non-null constraint.

```
describe('some test', () => {
  let foo!: SomeType;
  beforeAll(() => {
    foo = createFoo({}, {});    
  });

  it('returns something', () => {
    expect(foo.bar).toBe(true);
  });
});
```